# Java - Create comments by program way

Tags: java, comments, analyzer

Are there any libraries these allow to add comments with some information?
I have a core that searches security vulnerabilities in the code and I want to create a wrapper that adds information about that to the code. The library should allow me to create/read multiple line comments those contain markers, types, severities and etc, thanks

This is exmaple:

```
//<marker>: Issue #<num> <type> <severity> <?> <URL - optional>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Eclipse, you can utilize their ASTRewrite class to programmatically insert comments into your source code.

[Link to API](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2Frewrite%2FASTRewrite.html) 
[Link to Tutorial](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/06/add-comments-by-using-eclipse-jdt-astrewrite/)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following two papers:

- http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Erni08a.pdf
- http://scg.unibe.ch/archive/projects/Erni08b.pdf

These techniques aren't for the fainthearted, but they are approaches to the sort of thing that it sounds like you're after.